# Python tweepy find all tweets in the Netherlands

Tags: python, tweepy, geocode

UPDATE BOTTOM OF THE QUESTION:

I am attempting to create a script that generates all geocoded tweets in the Netherlands. I am a long way from getting there. While I was playing around with Tweepy I ran into a weird situation. I found a script online which could search for tweets containing a keyword. I tried to add a parameter checking for a geocode. I succeeded and the underneath script works. However, when I delete the geocode part of the tweepy.Cursos() call it does not work anymore. So this script works:

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = "???"
consumer_secret = "???"
access_token = "???"
access_token_secret = "???"

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="*",count=100,geocode="5.29126,52.132633,150km").items(100):
    print [tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.id, tweet.geo]
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.id])
```

UPDATE! 
Thank you for helping me so far. Now I have another question regarding my goal to create a script to gather all georeferenced tweets in the Netherlands.

The last part of my code should return all geocoded tweets in the Netherlands and write it into a CSV file. Unfortunately it only seems to take Tweets in the English language. Since there is no Dutch language setting, and Dutch people also Tweet in English, I do not want to set the language of the search. Why is it only searching Tweets in the English language? I do not know where I am setting this characteristic of the search.

Oh i turned around lat lon. Stupid mistake. Question is answered!

Comment: You can't just search for `*` it's an invalid query, even on twitter itself.

Comment: Someone told me if you fill in a star it just searches everything. It does work with the geocode attached. So for me it does not seem to be the problem. I can however test the code with a different string and will do that when I get home

Comment: I'm saying you can't search for `*` without the `geocode` parameter, that's why when you remove it, your code fails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only set your query string to `'*'` when also using the `geocode` parameter. A search for `q='*'` without a specified `geocode` is invalid.